# Как сделать вектор глобальным?

Tags: c++, vector

Как сделать вектор глобальным? Сейчас у меня вот так, но вектора при сборки разные?`

head.h:

```
#ifndef HEAD_H
#define HEAD_H


#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> mac_vec_p;

#endif  /* HEAD_H */`
```

`

main.cpp:

```
#include "head.h"
#include "Threading.h"

mac_vec_p mac_vec;

int main() {
std::cout << mac_vec[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Threading.cpp:

```
#include "Threading.h"
#include "head.h"

mac_vec_p mac_vec;
Threading::Threading() {

int N = 10

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    mac_vec.push_back (i);
}

}
```

После заполнения конструктором вектора "mac_vec", его элементы видны только в этом классе. В main.cpp - Segmentation fault

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, это два разных вектора, хотя и имеют одинаковое имя. Самый простой способ исправить - перед один из объявлений вектора написать extern.

```
extern mac_vec_p mac_vec;
```

Если мест использования нужно будет больше - то во всех новых также добавляем extern. Более правильная практика - вынести это в хедер, который подключать в нужных местах.

Но самая правильная практика - не использовать подобного, а передавать переменные как аргументы.